# Swift ambiguous overloaded + operator

Tags: swift, xcode, operator-overloading

It is probably so simple, but for a reason swift doesn't like my implementation of the + operator...
I've got a simple number protocol:

```
protocol Number : CustomStringConvertible {

    var doubleValue: Double { get }

}
```

A simple implementation of the same:

```
struct SimpleNumber : Number {

    let doubleValue: Double
    let description: String

    init(_ double: Double) {
        doubleValue = double
        description = "\(double)"
    }
}
```

and an extension for the operator overloading:

```
extension Number {

    static func + (lhs: Number, rhs: Number) -> Number {
        return SimpleNumber(lhs.doubleValue + rhs.doubleValue)
    }
}
```

So far, so good. But now, when I try to use that operator:

```
let number1: Number = SimpleNumber(1)
let number2: Number = SimpleNumber(2)
let number3: Number = number1 + number2;
```

Xcode tells me, that the operator is ambiguous.
So, why? My definition is the only one that fit's for two `Number` objects.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator shouldn't be inside the extension, but rather a global `func`. Replace your definition of `+` :

```
extension Number {    
    static func + (lhs: Number, rhs: Number) -> Number {
        return SimpleNumber(lhs.doubleValue + rhs.doubleValue)
    }
}
```

with simply

```
func + (lhs: Number, rhs: Number) -> Number {
    return SimpleNumber(lhs.doubleValue + rhs.doubleValue)
}
```

and it will work. I guess what you have done is created a static function `Number.+`, not the global function `+` that you are using...

Comment: > `I guess what you have done is created a static function Number.+` Also it look like adding function to protocol via extension also adds new function to all types implementing this extension with default implementation. So maybe code from question created **two** static functions with same signature `Number.+` *and* `SimpleNumber.+`, latter just call former by default. That *may be* the source of ambiguity.